# Using Ookii.Dialogs.dll in c#

Tags: c#, dll

Using `Ookii.Dialogs.dll` in windows form application (.net framework 3.5) gives error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I have placed the `dll` file inside `bin>>Debug` and then added reference to this `dll`. On button click event, when I call the method of this `dll`, it gives above error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: what is the stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add at least one button to the TaskDialog instance before calling Show, or you get that exception. It's also a good idea to wrap it in a `using`:

```
using (var td = new TaskDialog())
{
    var okButton = new TaskDialogButton(ButtonType.Ok));
    td.Buttons.Add(okButton);

    td.MainInstruction = "This is a dialog!"

    var whichButtonWasPressed = td.Show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you add a reference.

Enter the name of your class.

`Right click` on your class and use `Resolve Namespace`, that generate `using namespace ocrresponding`.

[image]

Comment: This is unrelated to the error message described by the poster (a `null` reference).

Comment: he can detect if he use good classes and namespace, it's always good to have good namespaces and classes, thank's O.R mapper for remarks

Comment: If the class name were not found, the code would not even compile and he would never get to see an exception message such as the one posted in the question.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with reference or namespace. I've used the following code: TaskDialog td = new TaskDialog(); td.Show();